# Error RC 1107 when running ressource compiler RC.exe

Tags: windows, api, resources

When I run this command from the command line, I get the error RC 1107:

```
d:\dev\projects\res\compiler\rc.exe RC /r /fo d:\dev\projects\res\output\manifest.res d:\dev\projects\res\compiler\manifest.rc
```

All mentioned paths exists.

I am not in the drive and path when I call this command, but I would tend to think that it should not matter since I am giving the paths explicitely.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
ChDrive "d:\"
ChDir "d:\dev\projects\res\compiler"
```

Then I called

```
"RC /r /fo ..."
```

from the command line.

I guess that I mixed up RC and rc.exe somehow. If anybody can give a clean explanation, I will of course accept his / her reply as the answer.